# OLTP-STAGGING-DW-DUPLICATES

Tags: data-warehouse, staging, star-schema, oltp

I have a project to extract data from an OLTP db to a Stagging star schema and then Datawarehouse db. I have a relationship : playlist<---(1-N)PlaylistTRack----->(1-N)Track--->(N-1)Sales. There is a concern in the group that duplicates will be created if I put ttables Playlist/playlistTrack/Track in 1 dimtable in Stagging bd, but i dont get how that comes about or if there really is a problem.

As we have searched, we found that we have to do a bridge table. But does that solve the problem if there is an actual one?

Comment: Hi - 1) I'm not sure why you would build a Staging area as a star schema? A staging area, as the name suggests, is for staging data, not for reporting on data which is where a star schema is required 2) There would only be duplicates if there was (potentially) duplicates in your source data. Only you can know that and only you can decide how to deal with it if it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a concern in the group that duplicates will be created if I put ttables Playlist/playlistTrack/Track in 1 dimtable

This is a valid concern. Your playlist and your track are two different conceptual things that relate to each other in a many-to-many way (a playlist can have multiple tracks and a track can appear in more than one playlist). You most certainly would *not* want to collapse this into a single table or you *will* have duplicates.

The bridge table that solves this is your `playlisttrack` table. The grain of that table is one track on one playlist, and the key is a combination of the keys to both the playlist and track dimensions.

```
playlist <--- playlisttrack ---> track
```

Now, if you have a *different* table playing the true role of a fact table (*sales*), then this doesn't change what's needed.   Your `sales` fact table would have a single key to `playlist`:

```
sales (fact) ---> playlist <--- playlisttrack ---> track
```

Your product dimension has been split into three tables in a pattern known as "snowflaking" but that's unavoidable. In this situation, while your `sales` table still acts as the real fact table, the bridge table (`playlisttrack`) is in a way a fact table of its own with its own granularity. It's important to realize this because you have to be careful when joining from `sales` through the bridge table to `track`, as that changes the granularity of your query. Unless your query filters on a single track, you would need to use careful `GROUP BY` logic with appropriate aggregation (`MAX` vs `SUM` on sales facts until grouped at the sales fact grain, then `SUM` only above that grouping, etc..) in any such query to avoid overcounting your sales facts.